# How do I prevent a loss of data? Bash script for counting - cronjob

Tags: shell, timer, cron

I have a small bash script that counts processed blocks from a blockchain. At time **A** I write the block height into the variable **block1** and at time **B** I write the block height into the variable **block2** In between I let the script sleep for 3600 seconds and then substract **block1** from **block2**

Everything runs smooth so far and I store the data into a mysql database. But now my question:

**How do I prevent a loss of data?**

If I want to count all blocks in a day, with letting the script sleep 24 hours dont seems to be a good idea. When the script fails after 23 hours sleeping it waited for nothing. How can I get rid of this problem?

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/nebkas

block1=$( blockchain status |jq .sync_info.latest_block_height | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' ) 

sleep 3600

block2=$( blockchain status |jq .sync_info.latest_block_height | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' ) 


count=$(expr $block2 - $block1)

DB_USER='user';
DB_PASSWD='password';
DB_HOST='host';
DB_NAME='database';
TABLE='table';



mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME --host=$DB_HOST<< EOF

INSERT INTO $TABLE (\`blocks\`) VALUES ( "$count");
EOF
```

Comment: as John3136 is alluding to ... instead of storing the delta heights in your db, store the raw heights (plus a date/time stamp) in your db; then you can always calculate the delta via a (relatively) simple SQL statement; by storing the raw data you can always calculate the delta height based on whatever interval you're interested in (eg, hourly, daily, weekly, etc); then you just need to decide how often (eg, every 5/10/15/60 mins) you sample the height ... which will depend on how you plan on using this data going forward

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It gaves me another point of view and helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `block1` to the database (perhaps with a timestamp) - if you do that every minute or 5 you can have a different script to pull the data you want out of the database.